# Any way to increase heap size of Graphileon Interactor?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there any way of increasing the heap size of the community version of Graphileon InterActor to increase performance and improve visualization of large networks?

*Installed on Windows using Docker Toolbox*

Thanks in advance!